# Corresponding SMD component - S280 label

Tags: surface-mount, identification

What kind of component is this? 
Looks like a capacitor but in a white color, measures give high ohm values like 60K

Manual: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18602178/Vestel%2B17MB37.pdf

[image: S280]

[image: S280]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: MB]

Last picture is from Google, for reference, same model

Comment: Yes, can we have a good picture of the mounted part?

Comment: Sure, i will do that. 10m...

Comment: I have added the photos

Comment: In context, it seems to be a solder able link or jumper, nothing else. A few are in the pdf. Mostly on power lines.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the provided schematic, it seems obvious that it is a solder bridge or jumper. The missing S289 and existing S280 shows that this version of the board is using the NOT version of Standby control.

Comment: I suspect about that at first view, but after use a multimeter i have no continuity in "S" components and give a high Ohm value.

Comment: I have addded a photo that i grab from google, I'm not sure but in photo looks like it have more components in that place. I'm trying to figure out what components are missing in my board

Comment: @TiagoConceição I understand, but the schematic seems to be very clear in this. Look at every other Snnn part. They all act as jumpers or enables.